# How do I add a wildcard for any subdiectory to redirect to the parent directory in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a number of old subdomains that also have subdirectories that need to be redirected with a wildcard in htaccess.

e.g.

```
www.newyork.domainname.co.uk
www.newyork.domainname.co.uk/accomodations/hotels
www.newyork.domainname.co.uk/what/ever/happens/here
```

to all be redirected just to

```
www.domainnam.co.uk/cities/newyork
```

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.(domainname\.co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.%2/cities/%1 [R=302,L]
```

Any thoughts on getting that third wildcard added in there? or if my cond/rule is way off or not?

Comment: Path segments are commonly matched with `[^/]+/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need relax pattern in `RewriteRule` to match any path:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.(domainname\.co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%2/cities/%1 [R=302,L]
```